# Finding possible values of $n$, for $\varphi(n) = 16$

Tags: number-theory, totient-function

So, I know that the integers that divide $16$ are $\{1, 2, 4, 8, 16\}$. And so the primes are  $\{2, 3, 5, 9, 17\}$. Now I am stuck on how to get my possible $n$'s. I know the answers are $n = 17, 34, 60, 40, 48, 32$ or ($17, 2\cdot 17, 2^2\cdot 3\cdot 5, 2^3\cdot 5, 2^4\cdot 3, 2^5$). But how do I find this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: 1) $9$ is not a prime. 2) now that you know $n=2^a3^b5^c17^d$, what is $\varphi(n)$ given that form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Quang Hoang points out, 9 is not a prime number, so the divisors of n are a subset $S \subset \{2,3,5,17\}$. If you know $S$, you can calculate $n$. For example with $S=\{2,3,5\}$ you get $\phi(n) = n\cdot\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{4}{5}=16 \Rightarrow n=60$. The equation delivers a valid solution iff its result is an integer and its prime factors are exactly the ones in $S$. So you need to try $2⁴=16$ subsets and you are done.